# Given notice of redundancy before 2 years employment, end date is after 2 years of employment - entitled to statutory redundancy pay?

Tags: united-kingdom

I work for a small company and due to lack of business they are changing their business model; as part of this my role is now being made redundant.

I was given my notice (a duration of 1 month) **before 2 years** of continuous employment.

On my confirmed last day of employment, I will have been working at the company for **2 years and 14 days**.

My employer **states I am not entitled to statutory redundancy pay** because I have worked with the company for less than 2 years.

**So my question is** - Is the relevant date calculated from when you were given notice, or your effective end date that decides if you are eligible for statutory redundancy?

**Food for thought...**

- If it turns out I am eligible for statutory redundancy, could the employer enforce gardening leave before the 2 years deadline to cancel my eligibility? (curious!)
- Halfway through my employment, I relocated abroad and now work remotely. Would this have any impact on my eligibility?

Comment: It would be interesting to read the statute(s) to which you refer. My "educated guess" is that the relevant date is the *end date*, that is, when termination of employment becomes *effective*. Otherwise, an employer could give overly anticipated notices to maximize the amount of statutory redundancy pay he can elude.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not a lawyer, but the UK Employment Rights Act of 1996, Part XI, Chapter IV, Section 155 says

> An employee does not have any right to a redundancy payment unless he
>   has been continuously employed for a period of not less than two years
>   ending with the relevant date. https://www.legislation.gov.uk/ukpga/1996/18/part/XI/chapter/IV

The key phrase there is "ending with the relevant date" which is defined in the UK Employment Rights Act of 1996, Part XI, Chapter IV, Section 145(2)(a) as follows:

> in relation to an employee whose contract of employment is terminated
>   by notice, whether given by his employer or by the employee, means the
>   **date on which the notice expires**,

Emphasis mine

So your answer is **Yes**.

Comment: Thanks Brian, I confirmed with ACAS as well and this is correct. The duration of employment is calculated from your start date, up until the termination of the contract (including your notice period basically).